# Does a "gimbal hinge" have the same degrees of freedom as a ball-and-socket joint?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, degrees-of-freedom

I am trying to design a joint to 3D print and considering different models. One model was a traditional spherical ball-and-socket joint. However, due to production issues, I am considering other models and was wondering if this model displayed below

[image: this]

has the same degrees of freedom as a ball-and-socket joint. In particular, I am confused about whether any non-commutativity issues exist as I read in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016937/) Math.SE post that it can be.

Can someone comment on

1. Will there be any degree of freedom restrictions from a model like this compared to a ball-and-socket joint?
2. What is the official name / term of the joint I have drawn below (if one exists)?

Answer (score 0):

Both joints will have three degrees of freedom, which you can parameterize as three rotations.

The issue of commutativity in the Math.SE post that you linked is really about something different.  It does not deal with the physical configurations that you can achieve (which is, I think, what really interests you here) but about how you get to various configurations through a sequence of rotations along different axes.  For sure you can get to any configuration that it looks like you can get from viewing the joint, both for this design and the ball and socket.